# Question about proof in Mathematical Logic for Mathematicians (Manin 2010)

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This is a bit of a pipe dream post, but perhaps someone has something.

In Chapter III, Manin works the construction of a model of ZFC in which the Continuum Hypothesis is false, essentially sending symbols of the axioms to random sets (functions from the von Neumann universe $V$ to a complete boolean algebra $B$), and creating highly specific definitions of the evaluations of the atomic formulae:

$$\|X \in Y\|, \|X = Y\|$$

in $B$ so that the these random sets are appropriately extensionally determined.

To deal with "existence" axioms, like the axiom of union, the idea is that there is a function that sends a random set $X$ to a formula which matches the template of the axiom, but the function ranges over so many values that it is a random class, rather than a random set. The trick is to restrict the class to a particular arbitrary ordinal, which makes it a random set.

Let $Y(X)$ be a random class, and $Y_\alpha(X)$ be the restriction of it to $V_\alpha^B$, the random equivalent of $V_\alpha$ in a classical universe. Manin writes $\|X \in Y\| = Y(X)$ for evocative reasons.

It is easy to see that $\|X \in Y_\alpha\| \leqslant \|X \in Y\|$, so to show the two equal we need to show the reverse inequality. This is done through manipulations of the boolean terms.

**Here is the question.** Proposition 6.6, the verification that $\|$Axiom of Union$\| = 1$ ends up proving the wrong inequality. Is this something I don't understand, or is the proof wrong?